# where to set `setInterval` when working with recompose?

Tags: javascript, react-native, recompose

I'm trying to build a simple timer that will start and stop on click.
all my project is functional component based (using recompose), so I'm not sure where to set the `setInterval`.

here is a thing I tried to play with until I was completely lost where to store the `setInterval` so I'll be able to clear it on `onStop` fn (that will fire on a button) - as in functional component there is no `this` that I can put the timer and remove it from ... what's the functional components way of doing it ?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQQZrm?editors=0010

any suggestions ?
- using react-native
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need here 3 different state handlers: `stopTimer`, `startTimer` and `updateValue`(I've used slightly different naming than your code did).

In `startTimer` you need to create timer that runs `updateValue` by timer. In other words you need to call indirectly one state handler from another.

There is [no way doing that](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/issues/392). But. You can split those handlers into 2 sets: "value + updateValue" and "stopTimer + startTimer + intervalId". Then you will be able to get state handlers from first set in second as `props`:

```
const EnchanceApp = compose(
  withStateHandlers({
    timer: 0,
  }, {
    updateValue: ({timer}) => 
        () => ({timer: timer + 1})
  }),
  withStateHandlers({
    timerId: 0,
  }, {
    startTimer: ({timerId}, {updateValue}) => 
        () => {
            clearInterval(timerId);
            return {
                timerId: setInterval(updateValue, 1000)
            };
        },
    stopTimer: ({timerId}) => 
        () => clearInterval(timerId)
  })
)(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

works perfect, my code sample:

```
const BgList = ({ bgs }) => (
  <PoseGroup>
    {bgs.map(item => <StyledBg key={item} style={{backgroundImage: 'url(/img/'+item+'.jpg)'}} />)}
  </PoseGroup>
);

const enhance = compose(
  withStateHanlders(
    () => ({
      index: 0,
      isVisible: false,
      bgs: _.shuffle([0,1,2,3]),
      timerId: 0,
    }),
    {
      startTimer: () => ({timerId}, {updateValue}) => {
        clearInterval(timerId);
        return {
            timerId: setInterval(updateValue, 5000)
        };
      },
      stopTimer: ({timerId}) => () => clearInterval(timerId),
      updateValue: ({bgs}) => 
        () => {
          return ({bgs: _.shuffle(bgs)})
        },
    },
  ),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      const {timerId, updateValue} = this.props;
      this.props.startTimer({timerId}, {updateValue})
    }
  }),

)

const BlockAnimated = enhance(({
  bgs
}) => {
  return (
    <BgList bgs={bgs} />
```